# Changing map_saver map size and resolution?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-saver, gmapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When running 'rosrun map_server map_saver -f my_map' to save a map generated by gmapping, the default size of the map appears to be 4000x4000 pixels and the resolution is 0.05 meters.  I could have sworn there was a way to change these defaults but now I can't find it.  I tried running gmapping with _delta:=0.01 but the map resolution was still 0.05.  Can the resolution and map size be changed during map creation?

Thanks!

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38737/changing-map_saver-map-size-and-resolution?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping documents xmin, xmax, delta, etc. to set its map size. That should change the size. If it doesn't it's a bug.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-07-13**:
Thanks @dornhege.  I was able to get the parameters to stick using a launch file around gmapping so perhaps I was just messing up trying to put them on the command line.